# Problems accessing Echonests /song/profile API via track_id

Tags: echonest

I'm trying to get the song profile of some mp3 via the Echonest API. With the /song/identify endpoint being removed (anybody knows why? since when?) I'm using the [/track/upload](http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/track.html#upload) and the [/track/profile](http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/track.html#profile) endpoints with success.

However with all mp3s I tried I never got a song_id field in the responses. And trying to access the [/song/profile](http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/song.html#profile) with a track_id parameter fails with the message "The Identifier specified does not exist".

I have no clue why this is happening. Isn't the /track/upload and /song/profile combination supposed to replace /song/identify? Or is there a mistake in my API usage?

## Example session

### /track/upload:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" "http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/track/upload?api_key={API_KEY}&filetype=mp3" --data-binary "@some.mp3"
{"response" : {
  "track" : {
     "bitrate" : 128,
     "status" : "pending",
     "samplerate" : 44100,
     "release" : "",
     "audio_md5" : "a778192f46b14aff8b77fd90ff3674bb",
     "artist" : "Michael Jackson",
     "analyzer_version" : "3.2.2",
     "title" : "Billie Jean",
     "id" : "TRAWIST152E4579002",
     "md5" : "b231bfa7d4ee4102e52b4495b10f4769"
  },
  "status" : {
     "version" : "4.2",
     "message" : "Success",
     "code" : 0
}}}
```

### /track/profile:

```
curl http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/track/profile\?api_key\={API_KEY}\&format\=json\&id\=TRAWIST152E4579002\&bucket\=audio_summary
{"response" : {
  "track" : {
     "bitrate" : 128,
     "status" : "complete",
     "samplerate" : 44100,
     "audio_summary" : {
        "speechiness" : 0.0425334097439946,
        "energy" : 0.591133932705891,
        "instrumentalness" : 0.0294479646761868,
        "valence" : 0.869460920263482,
        "danceability" : 0.928799121110435,
        "mode" : 0,
        "tempo" : 117.099,
        "duration" : 294.06041,
        "loudness" : -6.027,
        "key" : 11,
        "time_signature" : 4,
        "liveness" : 0.038297571421371,
        "acousticness" : 0.0121077539216603,
        "analysis_url" : "http://echonest-analysis.s3.amazonaws.com/TR/TRAWIST152E4579002/3/full.json?AWSAccessKeyId=AKI...&Expires=1455532971&Signature=ooy..."
     },
     "audio_md5" : "a778192f46b14aff8b77fd90ff3674bb",
     "artist" : "Michael Jackson",
     "analyzer_version" : "3.2.2",
     "title" : "Billie Jean",
     "id" : "TRAWIST152E4579002",
     "md5" : "b231bfa7d4ee4102e52b4495b10f4769"
  },
  "status" : {
     "version" : "4.2",
     "message" : "Success",
     "code" : 0
}}}
```

### /song/profile:

```
curl http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/profile\?api_key\={API_KEY}\&format\=json\&track_id\=TRAWIST152E4579002\&bucket\=audio_summary
{"response" : {
  "status" : {
     "version" : "4.2",
     "message" : "The Identifier specified does not exist: TRAWIST152E4579002",
     "code" : 5
}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find nothing wrong with your API requests. There is a note in the API however, under Track/Profile header: **Analysis Status**, that seems to point to the fact that tracks doesn't get resolved into EchoNest songs, see below.

> Note that song level information is not available for tracks that have
>   been analyzed with track/upload.

What you can do is create a [Taste Profile](http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/tasteprofile.html) using the track:id and it would get resolve into a EchoNest:song:id.

> When an item is properly resolved, the Echo Nest song ID is attached
>   to the item.

But this is a long way around, and considering the rate-limit is now down to 20/min, I don't know if I would bother. After EchoNest got bought by Spotify the public services are becoming deprecated and limited.